# ¿ Como verificar el correo de los usuarios en WordPress mediante código?

Tags: php, wordpress, validación, email, woocommerce

¿ Hay alguna manera de verificar que el email de un usuario que se registra en WordPress y de este modo asegurar que es verdadero ?
El usuario no debe registrarse en la base de datos hasta haber confirmado el email.

Me gustaría añadir una verificación para los usuarios que quieren registrarse en la tienda de WooCommerce y evitar los correos falsos y el SPA.
He buscado información y existe algún plugin con el que se puede crear una verificación del correo electrónico.

Yo queria hacer esto sin Plugins, unicamente con alguna función pero no tengo los conocimientos adecuados para crear algo parecido
¿ Pueden ayudarme? Gracias

**EDITO LA PREGUNTA**

Actualmente WordPress te permite registrarte introduciendo un correo cualquiera y directamente te inicia sesión, quizá yo no tenga la configuración bien echa del todo.
Luego te envia un correo para cambiar la contraseña, claro, si el correo es falso, nunca podrás restablecer la contraseña.
Pero cualquiera quiera puede llenar la base de datos de usuarios fantasma, ya que de este modo los usuarios se registran en el panel de WordPress.

Encontre una función la cual, me evita iniciar sesión sin verificar, pero me redireciona a la pagina 404 y solo dice el texto me indica que  el mensaje de la `funcion wc_add_notice` =

> "Error : Su cuenta debe estar activada antes de poder iniciar sesión.
> Por favor revise su correo electrónico."

Pero como digo, me lleva a la pagina 404.
Luego, voy al correo y tengo dos correos, el de WordPress , invitándome a establecer una contraseña, y el que genera esta función.

El problema esta que el usuario ya esta en la base de datos de WordPress y aparece en el panel de WordPress.

¿ Como puedo corregir esto ?
¿ Como evitar el registros sin pinchar al enlace de verificación ?

Espero puedan ayudarme

Esta es la función que encontre en un tutorial

```
//esto es solo para evitar que el usuario inicie sesión 
//automáticamente después de registrarse
function wc_registration_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect( '/sign-in/?q=');
        exit;
}
// cuando el usuario inicie sesión, verificaremos si el 
// correo electrónico de este tipo está verificado
function wp_authenticate_user( $userdata ) {
        $isActivated = get_user_meta($userdata->ID, 'is_activated', true);
        if ( !$isActivated ) {
                $userdata = new WP_Error(
                                'inkfool_confirmation_error',
                                __( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Su cuenta debe estar activada antes de poder iniciar sesión. Puede reenviar haciendo clic <a href="/sign-in/?u='.$userdata->ID.'">here</a>', 'inkfool' )
                                );
        }
        return $userdata;
}
//cuando un usuario se registra, debemos enviarle un correo electrónico 
//para verificar su cuenta
function my_user_register($user_id) {
        // obtener datos de usuario
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        // crear código md5 para verificar más tarde
        $code = md5(time());
        // convertirlo en un código para enviarlo al usuario por correo electrónico
        $string = array('id'=>$user_id, 'code'=>$code);
        // crear el código de activación y el estado de activación
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'is_activated', 0);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'activationcode', $code);
        // create the url
        $url = get_site_url(). '/sign-in/?p=' .base64_encode( serialize($string));
        // básicamente editaremos aquí para hacer esto más agradable
        $html = 'Por favor haga clic en los siguientes enlaces <br/><br/> <a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
        // send an email out to user
        wc_mail($user_info->user_email, __('Please activate your account'), $html);
}
//necesitamos esto para manejar todos los trucos de getty que hice
function my_init(){
        // comprobar si recibimos el mensaje de activación
        if(isset($_GET['p'])){
                $data = unserialize(base64_decode($_GET['p']));
                $code = get_user_meta($data['id'], 'activationcode', true);
                // comprobar si el código dado es el mismo que el nuestro
                if($code == $data['code']){
                        // update the db on the activation process
                        update_user_meta($data['id'], 'is_activated', 1);
                        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Success:</strong>Tu cuenta ha sido activada! ', 'inkfool' )  );
                }else{
                        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Error:</strong> La activación falla, comuníquese con nuestro administrador. ', 'inkfool' )  );
                }
        }
        if(isset($_GET['q'])){
                wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Error:</strong> Su cuenta debe estar activada antes de poder iniciar sesión. Por favor revise su correo electrónico.', 'inkfool' ) );
        }
        if(isset($_GET['u'])){
                my_user_register($_GET['u']);
                wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Succes:</strong> Su correo electrónico de activación ha sido reenviado. Por favor revise su correo electrónico.', 'inkfool' ) );
        }
}
// hooks handler
add_action( 'init', 'my_init' );
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'wc_registration_redirect');
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'wp_authenticate_user',10,2);
add_action('user_register', 'my_user_register',10,2);
```

Comment: Pones un formulario igual al registro, este formulario no registra nada en la base de datos, solo envía un correo con un enlace al registro verdadero. Adicionalmente puedes colocar en el link una especie de token encriptado par que valide la caducidad de este link y que sirva para que otros usuarios no puedan entrar directamente a la página de registro real

Comment: Gracias @Yussef , es por ello que vine aqui en busca de una solución, yo  no se como crear esto y es algo delicado, ya puede ser una puerta de acceso a intrusos

Comment: Lo que te propongo no es tan difícil, no obstante dudo que alguien te ponga la solución completa para que la copies y la pegues. 1) Creas un formulario de registro que envíe un correo sin guardar en BD, en el correo va un link a la página de registro que SI guarda en la BD. Para enviar correos por formularios hay pluggins.- 2) Generas un token para restringir el acceso directo a la página que si guarda en BD, así nadie puede entrar directamente, en Joomla hay un pluggin para esto, y si hay en joomla debe existir en WP

Comment: Por otro lado y no puedo dejar de comentarlo. Me indicas que es algo delicado, respetuosamente te digo, si no estas capacitado para hacer un trabajo no lo hagas. No me gustaría que un neurocirujano buscara como hacer una operación en "Stackoverflow medics"

Comment: Genial. Gracias por tu explicación. La verdad es que estoy empezando con php y si que, esto supera mis conocimientos con creces. Utilizare un Plugin y cuando este capacitado creare mi propia función para hacer esto. Para alguien con conocimientos no creo que esto sea muy dificil, otra cosa como bien dices, es que nadie me vaya a crear aqui esa función por que si. Muchas gracias te agradezco tu franqueza y seguire buscando la mejor manera de conseguir lo que busco teniendo en cuenta mis posibilidades. Sera un Plugin. Se suele decir que: hay más dias que longaniza. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, posiblemente la más fácil sería generando una clave secreta, enviarla por correo y pedirle al usuario que ingrese la clave secreta, si la clave es correcta el correo es válido, podrias probar algo como esto.

```
// Primero obtenemos el ID del usuario
// Puedes usar get_current_user o get_current_user_id
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Generamos un token secreto
// Puedes usar cualquier algoritmo para hacerlo
$secretToken = '546874';

// Guardamos el token secreto en metadatos del usuario
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'secretToken', $secretToken );

// Enviamos el Token Secreto al usuario por correo electrónico
$to = 'user@email.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'Su token secreto es:' . $secretToken;
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Una vez hayas generado la clave y guardado entonces puedes crear un formulario donde el usuario deba ingresar esa clave para verificar, entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
$secretToken = $_POST['token'];
$secretTokenUser = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'secretToken', true );

if ( $secretToken == $secretTokenUser ) :

    // El token es correto
    // Puedes cambiar el status del usuario, aceptar la cuenta, etc.

else :

    // El token es incorrecto
    // Puedes desactivar la cuenta, eliminarla, etc.

endif;
```

También podrias generar una url tipo, `mi-sitio.com/verificacion?token=secretToken`

Luego obtener el token con `$_Get['token'];` y hacer la misma verificación que hice arriba.

Todo esto dependerá de usted, estas son solo ideas de cómo podria hacerlo, tendrá que manejar un estado de usuario para aprobarlos en caso de querer activar o desactivar cuentas según sea necesario, podria usar un metadato de usuario para eso.

Comment: Gracias @JefferzonBol por tu tiempo, Realmente no se que puedo hacer con tu ejemplo. Veras que he añadido una función, pero que realmente no funciona, ya que el usuario se registra igualmente automaticamente en la base de datos

Comment: Y si en vez de usar el registro de Wordpress haces un registro propio tuyo? Luego llenas las tablas **users y  usermeta** con los datos mínimos de inicio de sesión. Claro esto lo tienes que probar muy bien antes de liberarlo al publico.

Comment: Gracias @OCHOA pero no creo que este capacitado para eso. Buscare documentación para intentarlo, pero creo que esto debe ser muy seguro como para añadir cualquier función. Me gustaría que fuera seguro y a prueba de ataques. Quiza si busco encuentro algún tutorial que te enseña a hacerlo en dos pasos, por ejemplo lei cosas sobre `hash`. Pero cualqueir experimentado podría registrarse y por la hora de registro entrar con el hash de otro cambiando la hora. Como digo, creo que es algo delicado para un pobre como yo. Ya tendremos más experiencia en el futuro

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar el correo electrónico de un usuario en WordPress, puede utilizar la función. Esta función toma dos argumentos: el campo por el que buscar y el valor que se va a buscar. Para buscar un usuario por correo electrónico, puede utilizar el campo.get_user_by()email

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo puede usar la función para verificar el correo electrónico de un usuario en WordPress:get_user_by()

```
// Check if the user exists by email
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $userdata->user_email );

if ( $user ) {
        // User was found, check if the account is activated
        $isActivated = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'is_activated', true);
        if ( !$isActivated ) {
                $userdata = new WP_Error(
                                'inkfool_confirmation_error',
                                __( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Your account must be activated before you can log in. You can resend the activation email by clicking <a href="/sign-in/?u='.$user->ID.'">here</a>', 'inkfool' )
                                );
        }
} else {
        // User was not found
        $userdata = new WP_Error(
                        'inkfool_user_not_found_error',
                        __( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> User not found', 'inkfool' )
                        );
}

return $userdata;
```

Este código primero buscará un usuario con el correo electrónico dado utilizando la función. Si se encuentra al usuario, comprobará si la cuenta está activada comprobando el valor del campo meta del usuario. Si la cuenta no está activada, devolverá un objeto con unget_user_by()is_activatedWP_Error